# Bootstrap - present confirmation modal after post back to controller

Tags: c#, model-view-controller

I am trying to create a Bootstrap modal pop up "Ticket successfully created" once you submit a form which posts data through to IActionResult to add to database. However my modal is like transparent with just text and I'm also getting a runtime error of : Obj ref not set to an instance of object

I have a feeling that modal popup is causing the passing of data back to the controller to not work. What is the way around this?

GetTicket view

```
@model Project.HelpDeskViewModel


<fieldset>
    @using (Html.BeginForm())
    {
        <div class="container">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="row m-4 text-center">
                        <div class="col-4">

                        </div>
                        <div class="col-4">
                            <h2 style="text-align:center;font-weight:bold">Get A Ticket</h2>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="row m-3">
                        <div class="col-4" style="text-align:left">
                            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.category)
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-4">
                            @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.category, new SelectList(Model.categoryList, "Value", "Text"), "Select category", new { @class = "form-control" })@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.category,
                        "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="row m-3">
                        <div class="col-4" style="text-align:left">
                            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.ticketDescription)
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-4">
                            @Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.ticketDescription, new { @class = "form-control" })@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ticketDescription,
                                "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                @*Modal for ticket creation*@
                    <div class="modal" id="MyModal" role="dialog">
                        <div class="modal-dialog">
                            <div class="model-content">
                                <div class="modal-header">
                                 <button class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                                <h4>Ticket Created</h4>
                                </div>
                                <div class="modal-body">
                                <p> Your Helpdesk ticket has been succesfully submitted</p>
                                 </div>
                                <div class="modal-footer">
                                <button class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal"> close</button>
                                </div>                                     
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>


                <div class="row m-3">
                    <div class="col-4">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-4" style="text-align:left">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary form-control" data-target="#MyModal" data-toggle="modal">Submit</button>
                    </div>
                </div>          
        </div>

    }
</fieldset>
```

Controller

```
        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult GetTicket(HelpDeskViewModel h)
        {
            HelpDeskViewModel sess = new HelpDeskViewModel();
            try
            {
                //session variable passing userID
                sess.userID = HttpContext.Session.GetString("userID");


                if (!ModelState.IsValid) return View(h);
                //h.empID = null; //add ticket record without employeeID - ticket hasn't been assigned yet
                h.userID = sess.userID; //add userID from session

                _db.helpdesk.Add(h);
                _db.SaveChanges();
            }


            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                global.gLogger.log.Debug("Debug message: ", ex.Message);
                global.gLogger.log.Error(new Exception(), ex.Message);
                global.gLogger.log.Error(new Exception(), ex.StackTrace);
                global.gLogger.log.Fatal("Fatal message: ", ex.Message); ;
            }
            return View("GetTicket");
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ViewBag` for open `bootstrap modal` after successfully return from **server** to **client**

### Client Side `View`

```
@if(ViewBag.SuccessfullyTicketCreated != null)
{
    <script>
        $('#myModal').modal('show'); // open model by use jQuery
    </script>
}
```

### Server side `Controller`

```
_db.SaveChanges();
ViewBag.SuccessfullyTicketCreated = true; // create ViewBag after savechange success
```

###### I hope help you simple way

Answer (score 0):

Only use of ajax call can solve your problem without creating any further issues. if you are not using jQuery, you can also send ajax call using Javascript using fetch() method.

```
<form id="form" action="/Controller/GetTicket" method="post">
    <div class="container">
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="row m-4 text-center">
                    <div class="col-4">

                    </div>
                    <div class="col-4">
                        <h2 style="text-align:center;font-weight:bold">Get A Ticket</h2>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="row m-3">
                    <div class="col-4" style="text-align:left">
                        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.category)
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-4">
                        @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.category, new SelectList(Model.categoryList, "Value", "Text"), "Select category", new { @class = "form-control" })@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.category,
                    "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="row m-3">
                    <div class="col-4" style="text-align:left">
                        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.ticketDescription)
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-4">
                        @Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.ticketDescription, new { @class = "form-control" })@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ticketDescription,
                            "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
            @*Modal for ticket creation*@
                <div class="modal" id="MyModal" role="dialog">
                    <div class="modal-dialog">
                        <div class="model-content">
                            <div class="modal-header">
                             <button class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                            <h4>Ticket Created</h4>
                            </div>
                            <div class="modal-body">
                            <p> Your Helpdesk ticket has been succesfully submitted</p>
                             </div>
                            <div class="modal-footer">
                            <button class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal"> close</button>
                            </div>                                     
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>


            <div class="row m-3">
                <div class="col-4">
                </div>
                <div class="col-4" style="text-align:left">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary form-control" data-target="#MyModal" data-toggle="modal">Submit</button>
                </div>
            </div>          
    </div>

</form>
```

Use Javascript:

```
<script> function onSubmit(){
 $.ajax({
  url:'/Controller/GetTicket',
   type:'post', 
  data: $('#form').serialize(), 
  success: function(){ 
  // code here;}
  })
}</script>
```